# Is shared hosting better for a SaaS application or cloud hosting?

Tags: web-hosting

I am creating a SaaS application and I plan to commercialise it. I want to know whether shared hosting will suffice or should I go in for a cloud hosting? I see that cloud hosting is very expensive and being a startup we cannot afford a high cost. Following we plan to do:

1) Run a cron job to backup the dbs every 6 hours.

2) Dynamically create a db and use it.

3) Send automated emails to the users.

4) Deploy a payment gateway.

Main thing would be that we will be executing lot of mysql queries. Max. traffic I anticipate for next 1 year is 10,000 per month.

I was thinking about business plan from hostgator for the SaaS app.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Having a payment gateway deployed, I assume that you'll be storing some sort of customer data, probably sensitive information, like address and payment data.  I ask you, is this data okay to store on a shared database?

Comment: How long do you anticipate a user spend on the site, how much will they be interacting with the site (page views), how heavy are your pages going to be?

Comment: we will be storing customer info in 256 bit encrypted format. we don't anticipate very heavy web pages. since, it ia an app we don't know how many pages as we are in the planning stage.

Comment: Gaurav, if you're going to store any credit card information, you need to host your site on PCI complaint hosting servers. Normal shared servers may not be suitable for storing CC information.  Regarding the cloud hosting, cloud hosting is getting cheaper now ... You can get a good public cloud hosting by $5 to $10 a month ...

Comment: @Jilesh: We will not store card info as in India there is no use of storing because the user has to manually authenticate the 3rd step specified by RBI.

Answer (score 0):

We will be going with cloud (pagodabox.com).

Answer (score 0):

Regular, non-cloud web hosting should suffice. There are a lot of successful e-commerce sites based on PHP, which use payment gateways, cron jobs, email marketing, etc.
Cloud hosting is much more expensive.